# how to merge local setState list to Redux list into one list - redux react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here i have a difficult situation. I have a locationData json in **JobsPanel** component which is saving location details based on one id(jobId). Now, in my component i have a part 'Configured Location' where i am calling the saved location data and make a setState list ('configuredList') from that json. Now, i have one more part in my application preliminary locations data using redux action calling other api and save into a list 'conLocations'.

Now, i am adding one location item 'conLocation' list (redux state) to 'configuredList'(setState) and updating the changes. It is working fine but last added item showing two times. After trial, i do understand that i have rendered two mapped list. How to merge that into one ? I have done so far this.

**configLocation function where i am retrieving last saved location from locationData json.**

```
/** Currently initialize and configure configuredList for retrieving existing job's location data */
   configLocation(locationData) {
    let configuredList = [];
    if (locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails != undefined) {
        locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item => {
            let listitem = { ...item };
            configuredList.push(listitem);
        });
    }
    this.setState({ configuredList });
}
```

**getLocationData function where i am merging two list that retrieved list and conLocations list and i am calling this function to other component where save changes or update changes operation is happening. It is working fine.**

```
getLocationData() {
        let saveableLocationlist = [];
        if (this.props.conLocations != null && this.state.configuredList != null) {
            const { configuredList } = this.state;
            const { conLocations } = this.props;
            let totalList = configuredList.concat(conLocations);
            saveableLocationlist = totalList;
        }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails: saveableLocationlist
        }
        return locationData;
    }
```

**here you can see i am updating the locationData json . By calling this function in jobspanel that updated locationData json is now available for my component in 'configLocation' function.**

My component code:

```
export class NewLocationPanel extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            open: false,
            configuredList: [],
            chkitems: []
        };
        this.configLocation = this.configLocation.bind(this);
        this.togglePanel = this.togglePanel.bind(this);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.allLocations = this.allLocations.bind(this);
        this.clearall = this.clearall.bind(this);
        this.getLocationData = this.getLocationData.bind(this);
        this.handleRemove = this.handleRemove.bind(this);
        this.removeConfigLocation = this.removeConfigLocation.bind(this);
        this.removeLocationAll = this.removeLocationAll.bind(this);
        this.handleChecklocation = this.handleChecklocation.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedAdded = this.handleCheckedAdded.bind(this);
        this.handleCheckedRemove = this.handleCheckedRemove.bind(this);
        this.handleActionButton = this.handleActionButton.bind(this);
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.loadData();
        if (this.props.locationData != null && this.props.locationData != undefined) {
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if ((prevProps.jobId != this.props.jobId || prevProps.locationData != this.props.locationData)) {
            this.configLocation(this.props.locationData);
        }
    }

//other codes

   /** Currently initialize and configure configuredList for retrieving existing job's location data */
   configLocation(locationData) {
    let configuredList = [];
    if (locationData.locations.locationDetails != null && locationData.locations.locationDetails != undefined) {
        locationData.locations.locationDetails.map(item => {
            let listitem = { ...item };
            configuredList.push(listitem);
        });
    }
    this.setState({ configuredList });
}


    /** updating locationData by saving changes - calling this function into jobsPanel */
    getLocationData() {
        let saveableLocationlist = [];
        if (this.props.conLocations != null && this.state.configuredList != null) {
            const { configuredList } = this.state;
            const { conLocations } = this.props;
            let totalList = configuredList.concat(conLocations);
            saveableLocationlist = totalList;
        }
        const locationData = {
            locationDetails: saveableLocationlist
        }
        return locationData;
    }

    //other codes

    render() {
        //const{configuredList} = this.state;
        const _labels = store.getLabels();
        let collapsedToggle = this.props.open ? 'collapsed' : ''
        return (

                {this.state.open ? (
                    <div className="panel-body">
                        <div className="row grid-divider">
                            <div className="col-sm-6">
                                <div className="col-padding">
                                    <div className="pos-div"><h4>Configured Location</h4>
                                    <div><table className="table configTableColor"><thead>{this.state.configuredList.map((locc, index) => <tr key={index}><th><input type="checkbox" onClick={() => this.handleCheckedRemove(locc.mruCode)} /><label></label></th><th className="configLocationInfo">{locc.mruCode} - {_labels[locc.division]} - {locc.country}</th><th className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={() => { this.removeConfigLocation(index) }} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></th></tr>)}</thead>



<tbody>
                                        {this.props.conLocations.map((loct, index) => <tr key={index}>
                                            <td><input type="checkbox" /><label></label></td>
                                            <td className="configLocationInfo">{loct.mruCode} - {_labels[loct.division]} - {loct.country}</td>
                                            <td className="text-right"><img alt="DeleteIcon" onClick={() => this.handleRemove(loct.mruCode)} className="deleteIconStyle" src="img/delete_large_active.png" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        )}
                                    </tbody></table></div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>) : null}
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        location: state.locationRed.location,
        conLocations: state.locationRed.conLocations,
        isChecked: state.locationRed.isChecked
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        loadData: () => { dispatch(loadData()) },
        addLocation: (mruCode) => { dispatch(addLocation(mruCode)) },
        addAllLocation: () => { dispatch(addAllLocation()) },
        removeLocation: (mruCode) => { dispatch(removeLocation(mruCode)) },
        removeAllLocation: () => { dispatch(removeAllLocation()) },
        checkboxState: (mruCode) => { dispatch(checkboxState(mruCode)) },
        checkedLocation: () => { dispatch(checkedLocation()) }
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, { withRef: true })(NewLocationPanel);
```

As you can see i am rendering two list. How to merged into one?

Jobs Panel component where i am initialize and saving locationData details

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LocationPanel from '../panels/NewLocationPanel';

class JobsPanelComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            jobDetailJson: this.props.jobDetailJson

        };
this.setLocationPanelRef = cRef =>{this.locationPanel = cRef;};

}
componentWillUnmount() {
        this.clearStates();
        this.clearRefs();
        this.clearBindings();
    }
          clearStates() {

        this.state.jobDetailJson = null;
        }
        clearRefs(){
               this.locationPanel = null;
                   }
        clearBindings(){
               this.setLocationPanelRef = null;
                       }
        componentWillMount() {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = this.props.jobDetailJson;
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.state.jobDetailJson = nextProps.jobDetailJson;
    }
     saveJobData(jobData){
      var locationData = null;
       if(some conditions){
        locationData = this.locationPanel.getWrappedInstance().getLocationData();
      }
    //more other lines not related to my mine
     }
      render(){
         var locationDataJson= null;
             if(this.state.jobDetailJson != null){
                     locationDataJson =this.state.jobDetailJson;
                   }
         return(<div className="panel-group" id="jobsPanelGroup">
               <LocationPanel ref={this.setLocationPanelRef} locationData ={locationDataJson} jobDetailJson={this.state.jobDetailJson} versionId={versionId} jobName={jobName} jobId={jobId} isForViewOnly={this.props.isForViewOnly} parentJobId={this.props.parentJobId} title="Location"/>
     //More coded lines for other things not related to my part
              );
         }


}
```

My application flow will be like - Configured Location(initial) configuredList -> conLocations (redux list) -> conLocations(add item) -> Configured Location(intermediate) configuredList + added item(conLocations) -> save changes -> Configured Location(final) - merged List

save changes /update locationData everything is in Jobs Panel but working fine. There is no problem. How to make changes in my component.

Answer (score 1):

The `mapStateToProps` function is passed both the redux state *and* the component's props. So you can combine your locations from redux and from props inside `mapStateToProps`:

```
// destructuring only the things we need from state (locationRed) and props (locationData)
const mapStateToProps = ({ locationRed }, { locationData }) => ({
  location: locationRed.location,
  // get a merged set
  conLocations: [...locationRed.conLocations, ...(locationData.locations.locationDetails || [])],
  isChecked: locationRed.isChecked
})
```

With this setup you could most likely eliminate your `configuredList` state and related update functions, your `componentDidUpdate` function and just render from `props.conLocations` instead of from state and props in two separate loops.

You could also dedupe locations or do any job id checks you need inside of `mapStateProps` when merging your lists. If it starts to gets a bit complicated in your `mapStateToProps`, you could take a look at memoized selectors like [reselect](https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect) that would make that a lot nicer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. If possible can you edit my component with your edits and some comments. So, i can follow up and try this further. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you think the concepts need more explanation, let me know and I can help there. But I'm not going to rewrite your components for you when you can do it yourself to test the solution.

Comment: Yes I need some help on that , So i need to understand if i eliminate that related update function how will i send updated locationData to other component. It is making me confused. ?? Sorry i am new to this kind of situation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The component you provided is not passing any data to another component—it's receiving data as props and from a redux store. Just make all of the data go through redux and any component can connect to the redux store and get it.

Comment: I have added Jobs component too where i initialize locationData. Now, problem is that two function in my location component 1. configLocation - where i retrieved the locationDetails 2. getLocationData() where i am merging redux conLocations list with previous retrieved list and calling this function in jobscomponent.

Comment: so i am confused how to do this retrieve and update operation if i consider conLocations only as you suggested